# Open files in a directory folder

Tags: c#, wpf

**[EDIT]**

I try to open a file from a folder in my base directory.

From the solution explorer, there is a folder "Docs" and a pdf file in it (tempPDF.pdf).
That will corresponds to a folder in my Project Folder. (e.g. Project\Docs) this is in the save level as bin and properties folders.

```
String assemblyPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = assemblyPath + "\\Docs\\tempPDF.pdf"
};
proc.Start();
```

I have already changed the **Build Action** to "Resource" and **Copy to Output Directory** to "Copy Always". Yet, the pdf file is not copies to the bin, nor the file can be specified by the program. I clean, build and rebuild the solution.

Path kept pointing to bin\Debug folder because this is where the executables is located but the files are location at the same level as bin.

I can simply specific my image in XAML by a path like "Images\img.png", and it will find the image relatively.

This is supposed to be a very simple question - open a PDF from a mouse click.

**[EDIT - with answer]**

Have to change **Build Action** to *"Embedded Resource"*, NOT **"Resource"** (Resource only copy a empty folder without the files). I don't know why though.

Comment: Drat! I only know the code behind solution. Must start learning XAML!

Comment: Would this be of help ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx

Comment: Aren't they installed relative to the application install directory? If so, you can use that and the relative path to get the full path to your PDF.

Comment: kenny, this is my question. How? I used System.Environment.CurrentDirectory but it's pointing to to bin/Debug, not to the folder I create in solution explorer (or the folder in the app root folder)

Comment: What's the build action on those docs? Are they resources?

Comment: They are just PDFs in a folder I add in solution explorer.

Comment: Right click them, select Properties and check the build action entry... (also use @alerts if you want people to be notified...)

Comment: @KMC - The reason its pointing to the Debug folder is thats where the application is when its started from within Visual Studio.  You should make sure the resource you want to display is copied when you build your solution.  This way its always in the same place.

Comment: So are so many selection in the Build Action ComboBox that I don't know how it helps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, there is no XAML solution for that. We cannot execute a process without code-behind assistance.

The URI you show is relative to the current assembly.
You can use the assembly directory path then append the relative path of the file.
It can be something like this:

```
String assemblyPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = assemblyPath + "\\Docs\\somePDF.pdf"
};
proc.Start();
```

If you want to put your documents in the application folder, you can also use that directory path instead of the assembly path:

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Comment: @KMC just add ../ then ? `Filename = assemblyPath + "..\\" + "\\Docs\\somePDF.pdf";` . But the assembly is your application root folder, of an application, so it's better to put your files (somePDF.pdf) to the application folder.

Comment: @KMC - It should have work because the code is correct. What is not correct is your not copying the file to the Debug folder.

Comment: Can you tell me the folder hierarchy of your images and actual pdf file after a compile.

Comment: If there is the case, click on your file in your solution explorer. Change your file property to resources/copy local

Comment: Have to change Build Action to "Embedded Resource", NOT "Resource"

Answer (score 0):

You can get assembly path as Nadzzz wrote. If you want to get '...bin' path  instead of '...bin\debug' you can use [Directory.GetParent method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
static function to open the folder a file is located in.  
I use in a static common class for many of my projects.

public static void ShowFileInFolder(string filepath)
{
        System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath);
        prc.Start();
}
```